# collapsed form-control is changing their attributes during size adjustment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm struggling with the following situation. I'm working on a website with some menu items. All items are showed correctly, expact the search bar in my collasped window. If a special width is exceeded the bar changing their style (position and gets some borders at the top and bottom - see image 3) and I don't know why this happens. I tried different examples but I don't get it. Any help and explanations why this happens would be nice. My solution shall look like my second image.

Image1:
[image: not collapsed]

Image2:
[image: first collapsed]

Image3:
[image: second different collapse]

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/bdd9U/1323/

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div> <!-- End Navbar Header -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="padding-right: 20px">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> Item2</a></li>
    </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=""/>
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
</div><!-- End Navbar Collapse -->
```

**CSS:**

```
@media (max-width: 820px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-form {
        width: auto;
        position: relative;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. The problem was the max-width of my media query. I think the uncontrolled behaviour was because of the standard width of the bootstrap size (768px) and my self defined 820px width.

**CSS:**

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-form {
        width: auto;
        position: relative;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the style **-webkit-box-shadow** of the class **.navbar-form**

```
.navbar-form {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    /* border-top: 1px solid transparent; */
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; */
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1),0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    /* box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1),0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1); */
}
```

That differs form the same class, for the media query with min-width: 768px:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-form {
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

so you can add this to your css file (with no media query):

```
.navbar-form {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Hey the border is gone, after i added border: 0px, -webkit-box-shadow: none and box-shadow: none to my .navbar-form class in my media query. But the position is still changing, and thats the more annoying problem